# How to switch from Trial to In App Purchases in UWP?

Tags: uwp, in-app-purchase, windows-store-apps

my UWP has currently only Trial and Full License. I want to remove having trial and make the app free but handle full license features with in app purchases and as well having some other in app purchases.
That means I created an in app purchase called "full version" and i want user to buy this in order to access all features of the app. 
Normally I can combine trials with other in app purchases (not full versuion IAP) but If User has trial, he cant buy any in app purchase. it returns error.
So I decided to create a durable in app purchase as "full version" to handle it myself.
My Question here is I have already people purchased full version of the app using trial /full version handled by Microsoft Store. How can I get that information and give these users full version features?

there is basically similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618703/uwp-trial-version-and-products-purchase-that-make-full-version-with-expiration) but the answer is a workaround and not working for me.

when I check `licenseInformation.ProductLicenses` object from `Windows.ApplicationModel.Store`, it doesnt have any license indicating that there is purchase?

EDIT:
licenseInformation.ProductLicenses returned is empty. there is not license indicated.
I found out [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/windows/uwp/monetize/use-receipts-to-verify-product-purchases) function  `GetAppReceiptAsync` which promises to return information about app and there is xml element called `LicenseType` but it doesnt seem to be correct information because for me, it returns  `LicenseType="Trial` instead of Full because when I check `CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.IsTrial` this one has false. I have already full version purchase so this one is correct but I dont know why App Receipt says that it is Trial.

Comment: When you get the `licenseInformation.ProductLicenses`, Is it a null list? If not, you can use the IsActive property of the [ProductLicense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.store.productlicense) objects to determine if the user is entitled to the in-app products.

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT please see my edit.

Comment: I saw that a same [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/fb2f09d9-60b4-4374-8d5a-c8ed41a9496e/how-to-switch-from-trial-to-in-app-purchases-in-uwp?forum=wpdevelop) in the MSDN had been followed, have you tried to use the new [Windows.Services.Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/get-license-info-for-apps-and-add-ons) API?

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT unfortunately it doesnt help either. I cant find any app purchase information or appreceipt function like older api has. IsTrial=false information wont help me because once I remove having trial but only ad-ons, it will be false for everybody and i cant distinguish between those who purchased app earlier

Comment: The [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/fb2f09d9-60b4-4374-8d5a-c8ed41a9496e/uwphow-to-switch-from-trial-to-in-app-purchases-in-uwp?forum=wpdevelop) had been followed, please check it.